# Robots.txt problem in subdirectory website (locale) and "/" character

Tags: robots.txt

We have two sites `mainsite.com` and `mainsite.com/de` where `/de` shows the german site.

We rely on 1 *robots.txt* file. It contains all the disallow links for `mainsite.com` that we set-up and copied it to `mainsite.com/de`.

```
Disallow: /media/sales/
Disallow: /media/tmp/
```

**Question:** doesn't the first slash (`/`) point to the root? How should we set up this robots to work also on the subdirectory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `/de` is not a sub-domain- it is a sub-directory. A sub-domain would be something like `de.example.com`.

And yes. You will need `/de/media/sales/` and `/de/media/tmp/`. You will always be working from the root directory.

Lastly, the robots.txt file must be in the root directory. You cannot create a robots.txt in the /de directory. It will never be seen. So your robots.txt file in the root will reference:

```
/media/sales/
/media/tmp/
/de/media/sales/
/de/media/tmp/
```

Comment: hmmm thanks. Typo. And there is no way to make the first directory *variable* so it would work for all /subdirectory/ sites?

Comment: @ShirtsofHolland I am not sure I understand the question. However, if I got it right, you may be able to use wild-cards, but generally speaking, you are better off specifying all directories specifically to make sure that bots fully understand. Here is a simple explanation: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: In terms of "wildcards", you can do something like `/*/media/sales/` for _all_ subdirectories. But note that this is an extension to the "standard". closetnoc's comment still applies. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt